# Display and follow mount namespace tree peer group IDs

Tags: mount, namespace, container

Linux has [mount namespaces](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html) for process-scoped mount trees via the "shared subtrees" feature.

When you examine `/proc/$pid/mountinfo` of processes in a parent/child mount namespace, you can see peer group relationships per [sharedsubtree.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt). For example, the outer namespace's mount for `/child` might have tag `shared:538`. Within the child mount namespace created by `unshare -M`, a child process might see `master:538` for the same mount.

But sometimes those IDs don't match up. The child process peer group ID doesn't appear to exist from the perspective of the parent process. For example, in my `containerd` from the perspective of `nsenter -t 1 --all` I see the `/proc/1/mountinfo` entry for the container mount as having `shared:538`. But from the perspective of `nsenter -t $in_container_pid --all cat /proc/self/mountinfo` I see `master:532`.

I presume this is due to an intermediate process that set up the container environment then `exec`'d the container guest process within the container.

Is there any way to list these mount group peer IDs and map them to a process tree and/or mount namespace inode? Presumably this peer-group heirarchy is maintained in the kernel somewhere, but I can't find it exposed by any utility like `lsns` or in sysfs.